# preg_replace output is wrong

Tags: php, regex, encoding

Hello got the following problems

First: if ÄÖÜ is provided with the regex the trademark sign replacement is producing a addional char �.:

Second: If I do a string loop through the result all special chars are �.

Question is, why is this happen, and what can I do against it? (Second question is not so nessesasary but interesting)

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$testtxt = 'MicrÖsüft W!ndows® is a trÄdemark of Microfrost™ ©2012!';

$r =  preg_replace('#[^\w\s\däöüß%\!\?\.,\:\-_\[\]ÄÖÜ]#is', 'X', $testtxt);
echo $testtxt, '<br>', $r;
echo '<hr>';
for($i = 0, $size = strlen($r); $i < $size; ++$i) {
    echo $r[$i], '=', ord($r[$i]), '<br>';
}
```

Result:

```
MicrÖsüft W!ndows® is a trÄdemark of Microfrost™ ©2012!
MicrÖsüft W!ndowsXX is a trÄdemark of MicrofrostX�X XX2012!
M=77
i=105
c=99
r=114
�=195
�=150....
```

Expected:

```
MicrÖsüft W!ndows® is a trÄdemark of Microfrost™ ©2012!
MicrÖsüft W!ndowsXX is a trÄdemark of MicrofrostXX XX2012!
M=77
i=105
c=99
r=114
Ö=195
s=150....
```

Comment: Have you checked your file's encoding?

Comment: Yes I have checked the file encoding. It is setted to utf-8.

Answer (score 2):

You're using strlen and ord functions which are not compatible with multibyte characters. 
The following code should show you the amount of bytes per character:

```
for($i = 0, $size = mb_strlen($r); $i < $size; ++$i) {
    echo $r[$i], '=', strlen($r[$i]), '<br>';
}
```

Second, you should add the UTF-8 modifier to your regexp:

```
$r =  preg_replace('#[^\w\s\däöüß%\!\?\.,\:\-_\[\]ÄÖÜ]#isu', 'X', $testtxt)
```

Comment: Thanks mate that "u" modifier does it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure, but you could try adding the "u" modifier to the regex in preg_replace(). Or try using [mb_eregi_replace()](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-eregi-replace.php).

Also, are you sure it's okay to use ord()? It is written in the manual that it returns the *ASCII* value (which, I strongly suspect, means that for multibyte characters it'll return the value of the first byte).

Comment: Hmm, what really makes me wonder is, that you can not access a char via the $string[$position] command. I thought that this is a build in language function.

After reconsidering I think the only way to loop trough a utf-8 string is via mb_substr.